# Plone with Apache Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, plone

I have a plone zinstance set up through Apache Proxy on OS X Server 10.5.  The server is set up with a single vhost on port 80, with Proxy & Proxypass directives to the Plone zinstance:

```
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/server:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/server:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/
```

However, I have some static HTML and PHP content that I want to display in an iframe via the plone site.  I'm thinking I'll need to set up another vhost on a different port, then just specify the port # inline?

Comment: I've gotten it to where I can see the iframe in plone.  I'm serving an additional vhost on port 8888 available to localhost only.  I can see the first page, but if I try to click one of the links inside that should take me to a php page, it just sits there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have: anything in `/images`, `/styles`, `/scripts` does not go to Plone.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyTimeout 600
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass /styles !
ProxyPass /scripts !

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|scripts|styles|projects)/(.*)

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```